# Android - Toggling width & height on ACTION_MOVE

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, touch-event, android-togglebutton

Hey i'm a beginner in programming and stuff, and i need a little bit help from anyone here, so...

i have some imageview with shrink/grow effect on ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN , and i want to toggle the width and height when the MotionEvent switch to ACTION_MOVE,

so whenever touch X and Y enter the position of imageview it would grow the scale for once (because my imageview keep getting smaller whenever the ACTION_MOVE is on), 
and when touch X and Y exit the position of imageview it would reset the scale to original, can anyone teach me how to do that?

here's my code:

```
public void scale(View v, MotionEvent event){
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams mnt = v.getLayoutParams();
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mnt.height *= 1.1;
            mnt.width *= 1.1;
            v.setLayoutParams(mnt);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mnt.height /= 1.1;
            mnt.width /= 1.1;
            v.setLayoutParams(mnt);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mnt.height /= 1.1;
            mnt.width /= 1.1;
            v.setLayoutParams(mnt);
            break;
    }
}
```

P.S sorry for my bad english...